# Recursive Cartesian Product Function Racket

Tags: recursion, racket

I am trying to implement a recursive function to find the cartesian product of two sets. The code I have currently is as follows:

```
    (define (cartesian-product set-1 set-2)
        (let (b (set 2))
             (cond [(empty? set-1) '()]
                   [(empty? set-2)  (cartesian-product (rest set-1) b)] 
                   [else (append (list (list (first set-1) (first set-2))) (cartesian product set-1 (rest set-2)))]))))
```

However, there are errors with my logic that I haven't been able to pinpoint precisely. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something with two loops instead of one?

```
(define (cartesian-product set-1 set-2)
  (define (cartesian-product-helper element set)
    (if (empty? set)
        set
        (cons (list element (first set))
              (cartesian-product-helper element (rest set)))))
  (if (or (empty? set-1)
          (empty? set-2))
      empty
      (cons (cartesian-product-helper (first set-1) set-2)
            (cartesian-product (rest set-1) set-2))))
```

You found the issue in your logic and attempted to save `set-2` (which you typo'd as `(set 2)`) in `b`, but this value will be overwritten at each recursive call. If you call the helper function instead, which loops through all elements of one set along with the first element of the other set, your issue goes away.

```
Welcome to DrRacket, version 6.1.1 [3m].
Language: racket; memory limit: 128 MB.
> (cartesian-product '(1 2 3) '(x y z))
'(((1 x) (1 y) (1 z))
  ((2 x) (2 y) (2 z))
  ((3 x) (3 y) (3 z)))
> (cartesian-product '(1 2 3) '())
'()
> (cartesian-product '() '(x y z))
'()
```

Alternatively, something more racket-like:

```
(define (cartesian-product set-1 set-2)
  (if (or (empty? set-1)
          (empty? set-2))
      empty
      (for/list ([i set-1])
        (for/list ([j set-2])
          (list i j)))))
```