# How to get the multiplication of two lists in Lisp or Scheme?

Tags: scheme, lisp

I think I'd have to dig into SICP later, but if it is two lists:

```
a b c d
1 2 3
```

Is there a standard way to get the multiplication of them in 2, 3 or 4 lines?

So the desired result is

```
a1 a2 a3 b1 b2 b3 ... d1 d2 d3
```

If we use any imperative language / method to do it, it is quite simple, but if we use Lisp / Scheme in a functional way (by declarative method), is there a standard method it is done?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Recursive Cartesian Product Function Racket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28558134/recursive-cartesian-product-function-racket)

Comment: possibly... but the answers in them as so complicated...  I am a bit rusty in Scheme or Lisp (as I took it long time ago in college), but let's say if I use JavaScript the functional way, I can do it in 1 line: https://jsfiddle.net/smoaqn18/1/ (you have to click on the `Console (1)` to see the result.  But I am not sure if this is a standard way if it is done in Lisp as well

Comment: also, even though it is short, it does have the extra cost of creating a 2D array and then flatten it

Comment: @StefanieGauss that _is_ the tradeoff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DrRacket has [`cartesian-product`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Flist..rkt%29._cartesian-product%29%29):

```
(require racket/list)
(cartesian-product '(a b c d) '(1 2 3))
```

And you can rewrite your Javascript code this way (in Racket):

```
> (apply append (map (lambda (a) (map (lambda (b) (list a b))
                                 '(1 2 3)))
                '(a b c d)))

'((a 1) (a 2) (a 3) (b 1) (b 2) (b 3) (c 1) (c 2) (c 3) (d 1) (d 2) (d 3))
```

Or in Common Lisp:

```
CL-USER 1 > (apply #'append (mapcar (lambda (a) (mapcar (lambda (b) (list a b))
                                 '(1 2 3)))
                '(a b c d)))

((A 1) (A 2) (A 3) (B 1) (B 2) (B 3) (C 1) (C 2) (C 3) (D 1) (D 2) (D 3))
```

Comment: it does look like your Lisp method is also by two `map`s and an `append` (which probably is like a flatten?)... so I guess this is like a standard way to do it in Lisp but not a more direct way? So I guess it belongs to some sort of "bag of tricks" -- to do cartesian product, just do two maps and one flatten

Comment: @StefanieGauss That depends on used Lisp dialect- DrRacket has `cartesian-product` from `racket/list`, Common Lisp has `#'alexandria:map-product`, Clojure has `clojure.math.combinatorics/cartesian-product` and so on- and that solution with two `map`s and `append` is also usable.

Comment: ok, I think I get what your `append` is... it is like concat everything, like an `inject` or `reduce` of `concat`: https://jsfiddle.net/7sxzwcLg/1/

Comment: @StefanieGauss a map into lists followed by appending them together _is_ a flatMap. which is a "functional" way to simulate nested loops building the result list, emitting its elements in the innermost loop.